# Remove a legend entry in a plot-ly scatter plot

Tags: r, plotly, trace

I have the following code to generate a 3-D scatter plot:

```
IU_wide_2_filtered %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~CI_scale, y = ~FI_scale, z = ~ConI_scale, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~CI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 1], y = ~FI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 1], z = ~ConI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 1], 
            type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", 
            marker = list(size = 5, symbol = "circle", color = "#303030"),
            name = "Cluster 1") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~CI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 2], y = ~FI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 2], z = ~ConI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 2], 
            type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", 
            marker = list(size = 5, symbol = "diamond", color = "#808080"),
            name = "Cluster 2") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~CI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 3], y = ~FI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 3], z = ~ConI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 3], 
            type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", 
           marker = list(size = 5, symbol = "cross", color = "#000000"),
           name = "Cluster 3") %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "CI_scale"),
                      yaxis = list(title = "FI_scale"),
                      zaxis = list(title = "ConI_scale"),
                      showlegend = TRUE))
```

Which results in:

[image]

There's the "trace 0" legend entry, which should not be there. How do I remove it?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Use showlegend = FALSE inside the trace. See also: https://plotly.com/r/legend/

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I was able to solve it as follows: IU_wide_2_filtered %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~CI_scale, y = ~FI_scale, z = ~ConI_scale, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~CI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 1], y = ~FI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 1], z = ~ConI_scale[clus_CI_FI_ConI == 1], 
            type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", 
            marker = list(size = 5, symbol = "circle", color = "#303030"),
            name = "Cluster 1", showlegend = TRUE) %>%
  ...

Comment: @HB Please post you solution as an answer and vote for it. Ty.